# Avoiding backticks in mysql workbench

Tags: mysql-workbench

In mySQL Workbench, when using "copy to clipboard" on a table, the sql statement which is created contains back ticks (`) that wrap column names, table names etc.
Is there a way to avoid it?

Answer (score 2):

Once you have selected the rows you want, you need to right click and select 'copy rows unquoted'. 
I cant post a example due to being a new member.